# Water falling, why does it spin?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, surface-tension, turbulence

I have noticed that water, when falling will rotate. Looking closely at a thin stream from a faucet and placing a flat object mid stream you will see the water is rotating. The further down the stream you go you will notice the rotation is much quicker. Am I confused at this occurrence or is there a reason? I can only come up with the rotation of the earth taking into affect.

Comment: I doubt that it has anything to do with the rotation of the Earth.

Comment: I feel they same way, but I have no other answer for it.

Comment: The surrounding air could produce some torque to rotate it. I am just guessing though.

Comment: Water does not spin coming out of my faucet.  Assuming your faucet causes water to come out rotating, conservation of angular momentum would cause the water to rotate faster farther down the stream because the stream narrows farther down.

Comment: I tested with an almost complete block of air flow and the result was unchanging.

Comment: Have you tested it Brandon? I have done so on many faucets and even having a cup set on a rig to pour water at a fine stream and received the same results.

Comment: Yes, the speed of rotation will increase because the stream becomes narrower. No doubt about that. What causes the water to rotate is difficult to guess. Could be the shape of the opening of the faucet.

Comment: I thought the faucet shape would come into affect but still had the same results with cups with different pourers.

Comment: It is very difficult to make a faucet, or pour from a cup, without imparting *some* rotation to the water. As @Parth said, it will rotate faster as the diameter of the stream decreases.

Comment: I understand the pressure and friction can cause some rotation. A tube fixed upright with only gravity pulling downward should cause the water to fall faster from the middle of the stream due to the friction on the outside touching the tube causing drag. But the water still rotates the same way.

Comment: What is preventing the falling water from rotating? Nothing. And I think this is the conceptual answer.

Comment: Agree with @CraigFeinstein and Mike, so many forces are acting on the stream from all directions. Some torque is bound to be there.

Comment: I think the spin is caused by upstream bends in the water piping (slanted bends plus gravity).

Comment: Which direction does it rotate? Is it always the same direction?

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest answer to this question would be that the stream of water has a number of **forces** acting on it (gravity, air drag) from **many directions**. Some **torque** is bound to be produced as the stream falls through the air. If you throw a ball or any small object from a height, it rotates, no matter how you drop it. Same logic applies here.

As far as the speed of rotation increasing as it goes down is concerned, the reason has to be that the stream is getting narrower, so it has to rotate faster to account for the decrease in the radius due to **Conservation of Angular Momentum**.

Comment: I think you can improve the last sentence. Angular momentum is not lost.

Comment: It says 'to account' for the loss in angular momentum. The increase in velocity is compensating for the decrease in radius.

Comment: Exactly, you mean that the velocity increases to account for the change in radius. Angular momentum isn't lost. You're right. Just change the phrasing.

Comment: I've dropped many objects that don't rotate for drop tests at precise angles... What would cause a torque of significant magnitude to cause an observed change in speed? (gravity acts on the center of mass, and for nearly symmetric objects the air drag would similarly act near the center of mass)

Comment: There is no torque of magnitude more significant. Those very small magnitude torques are eventually massively magnified in angular velocity as the water flow contracts due to the conservation of angular momentum.